# Trouble With Conditional Formatting Formula (Basic Code I think?) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

`=IF(AND($C18="Actual B&P"),($D18/$E18)>=lower0.11,($D18/$E18)<=upper0.25)`

This is my formula I currently have.

I want to highlight cells titled Actual B&P in column C that have a VALUE that falls between `11%` and `25%`.

The equation for the VALUE is Total BP `$D18` divided by Approved Budget BP `$E18`

There has to be an easy way to do this, because what I currently have is not working.

I need this to be a CONDITIONAL FORMATTING  value in excel and I am pretty sure it doesn't allow for arrays?

any help would be great!!

Comment: =IF(AND($C18="Actual B&P"),AND(($D18/$E18)>=0.11,($D18/$E18)<=0.25))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the IF() wrapper.

You have the `)` wrong:

```
=AND($C18="Actual B&P",$D18/$E18>=0.11,$D18/$E18<=0.25)
```